# Closed-form Solution of an Integral Equation

Tags: calculus, special-functions, improper-integrals

Recently, I get stuck in an equation, and I would like to obtain an closed-form solution of an equation, which is given as
$$
\int_1^\infty\frac{x}{t^\alpha-x}dt=c,
$$
where $\alpha>1$ and $c>0$ are constants. Is it possible to obtain the expression of $x$, where $x\in\left(0,1\right)$? If not, can we get the scaling relation between $x$ and parameters $\alpha$ and $c$? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your integral can be written as $\dfrac{x}{a} \Phi\left(x,1,1 - 1/a\right)$
where $\Phi$ is the Lerch Phi function.  I doubt that there's a closed-form 
solution for $x$ in general, or a scaling relation.  You could get a series
expansion:

$$ \eqalign{x &=  \left( a-1 \right) c-{\frac { \left( a-1 \right) ^{3}}{2\,a-1}}{c}
^{2}+{\frac { \left( 2\,{a}^{2}-4\,a+1 \right)  \left( a-1 \right) ^{
4}}{ \left( 2\,a-1 \right) ^{2} \left( 3\,a-1 \right) }}{c}^{3}\cr &-{
\frac { \left( 4\,{a}^{4}-19\,{a}^{3}+25\,{a}^{2}-9\,a+1 \right) 
 \left( a-1 \right) ^{5}}{ \left( 2\,a-1 \right) ^{3} \left( 3\,a-1
 \right)  \left( 4\,a-1 \right) }}{c}^{4}\cr &+{\frac { \left( 24\,{a}^{7}-
210\,{a}^{6}+624\,{a}^{5}-789\,{a}^{4}+450\,{a}^{3}-128\,{a}^{2}+18\,a
-1 \right)  \left( a-1 \right) ^{6}}{ \left( 3\,a-1 \right) ^{2}
 \left( 4\,a-1 \right)  \left( 5\,a-1 \right)  \left( 2\,a-1 \right) ^
{4}}}{c}^{5}+\ldots}
$$